# Delete foreign tables first and primary key tables next in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Hi i have one doubt in postgres. In database  have 100 tables . few tables have primary key and foreign key relationship and few tables do not have relationship. 
Here I want delete all tables useing delete statement. 
When I tried delete statement for all tables that time getting error pk and fk violation.

How will delete fk first and pk tables.

Could you tell me how to write a query to achieve this task I  postgres.

Comment: do you want to delete tables or rows from the table?

Comment: Rows values from table

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `CASCADE` option.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html -> item 5.3.5